# Joomla 3.3.6 admin panel not working

Tags: joomla, admin

The buttons on the admin panel of my joomla site suddenly wont work anymore,

The dropdown works but when i hit a button it doesnt work.

Almost all buttons, i cant view my articles, categories or menus anymore and a lot of components.

Please help me!

Comment: Check your browser console for any errors and also your error logs

Comment: If you've changed some code, post your changes here. If this is not a programming question it's off-topic and you should ask elsewhere.

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS localhost/WEBSITE/administrator/index.php?option=com_modules&view=modules <<<    this is what chrome developer tool says..     and i dont know what kind of changes i made, so i cant post any code. i just started up today and nothing works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons for this problem to happen:

- One (or more) core JavaScript files was (were) hacked.
- You have recently installed an extension (typically a global system plugin) that created a conflict between JavaScript libraries

Try disabling, from phpMyAdmin, the recently installed plugin(s). Also try overriding all your core Joomla files with a fresh copy of Joomla.

Also make sure you delete your browser cache!

Comment: I already found the solution, somehow something made changes in my bootstrap.min.js but ty anyway for taking the time to help me out

Answer (score 0):

1- Go to yoursite/administrator/index.php

2- In the left side menu, most probably in Maintenance part ... checking joomla is stuck (probably some files damaged)

3- Select reinstall joomla core files.